# Error: Command not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, rvm

I at last found a chart plugin that I could understand on [this](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/07/23/open-flash-chart-ii-plugin-for-ruby-on-rails-ofc2/comment-page-6/#comment-19004) page now I was doing exactly the steps, I got this errors:

```
$ rails testing_ofc_2
Error: Command not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:...
```

also when I type some command with rvm I got this error

```
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the instructions are out of date. Try

```
$ rails new testing_ofc_2
$ cd testing_ofc_2
$ script/rails plugin install git://github.com/pullmonkey/open_flash_chart.git
```

Comment: when I type the third line it shows me this:    -bash: script/plugin: No such file or directory